# Why does updateChilden with POJO work with Firebase Android SDK but not with Firebase Server SDK?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, firebase

Minimum example:

```
public class Post {
    public String id;
    public String name;
}
```

On Android side I call:

```
Post post = new Post("some id", "some name");
final Map<String, Object> updates = new HashMap<>();
updates.put("posts/" + post.id, post);
databaseReference.updateChildren(updates).addOnCompleteListener(listener);
```

and it works.
But if I do the same thing on the Server (AppEngine Java Env) it fails with Exception:

`Failed to parse node with class class Post firebase`

It works when I do the `toMap()` workaround on the Server but why do I need that?
It's just a simple POJO and it works on Android side...

Edit: Don't worry about the id, it's just an exemplary value here. I use the actual ids from FireBase in both the App and the Server.

Thanks

Comment: Your code looks like trying to update a location with an empty HashMap.  The Post isn't being used at all, except to compose the name of the location.  And it's not clear to me what that location is, given that post doesn't have a toString() method describing how it would render for string concatenation.

Comment: oh, I forgot the second parameter on put :) sorry... also I do have an id field in my model which I wanted to omit for brevity. Now it should make more sense. The point is still that the code works on Android and not on AppEngine though.

Comment: can you post your server code where the error occurs

Comment: I can run the equivalent of this code running locally outside of GAE with no problem.  You might be doing something wrong during init or some other point.  I suggest you get your code working in a local process first, then try to get it to work on GAE.

Comment: @Linxy: this is both the server and the Android code. My question is why does it work on Android but not on GAE? I have the GAE instance in usage for a ton of other stuff and it all works as long as I'm not posting POJOs but Maps.

@DougStevenson As I said, I too can run the code without any problems outside of GAE. The problem is within GAE. Why does it only work when I do the `toMap()` workaround there? They are identical objects and identical calls. The database reference setup works perfect and everything around it as well. My question is really only exactly the POJO problem on GAE.